# After clone of ASP.NET Core Web API project on other computer receiving MediatR error

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, mediatr

In my computer application works fine, but other computers receiving next error after trying handle any request:

> Error constructing handler for request of type MediatR.IRequestHandler`2[Application.User.Register+Command,Application.User.User]. Register your handlers with the container. See the samples in GitHub for examples
>   connection string

I register MediatR with following line in my Startup.cs:

```
services.AddMediatR(typeof(List.Handler).Assembly);
```

My Startup class:

```
 public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(opt =>
            {
                opt.UseSqlite(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
            });
            services.AddCors(opt =>
            {
                opt.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy", policy =>
                {
                    policy.AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod().WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000");
                });
            });

            services.AddMvc(opt => 
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
                opt.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            })
                .AddFluentValidation(cfg => cfg.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<Create>())
                .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);

            var builder = services.AddIdentityCore<AppUser>();
            var identityBuilder = new IdentityBuilder(builder.UserType, builder.Services);
            identityBuilder.AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataContext>();
            identityBuilder.AddSignInManager<SignInManager<AppUser>>();

            var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["TokenKey"]));
            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(opt =>
                {
                    opt.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        IssuerSigningKey = key,
                        ValidateAudience = false,
                        ValidateIssuer = false
                    };
                });

            services.AddScoped<IJwtGenerator, JwtGenerator>();
            services.AddScoped<IUserAccessor, UserAccessor>();
            services.AddMediatR(typeof(List.Handler).Assembly);
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseMiddleware<ErrorHandlingMiddleware>();
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                //app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
              //  app.UseHsts();
            }

            //  app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseCors("CorsPolicy");
            app.UseMvc();
        }
    }
```

Problem is that i cannot reproduce same issue on my computer.

Comment: did you clean and rebuild the solution?

Comment: Yes, didn't help

Comment: Make sure that for the class `User.Register` Handler, all of your dependencies are registered in the services collection, for some reason one of them is missing

Comment: Doublechecked, in my PC where i developed works fine, but with same configuration on laptop receiving error

Comment: can you share your startup file, and which dependencies the `User.Register` Handler has?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was on another level:

```
 var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["TokenKey"]));
```

It was problem with reading Configuration. After fixing it, all works as designed.